# Get Name of Id from Json using linq

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, lambda

I have JSON as follows

```
{
  "code": "0",
  "message": "success",
  "appointments": [
    {
      "patient_id": "1",
      "patient_name": "Jairaj Test",
    },
    {
      "patient_id": "2",
      "physician_name": "Test Physician",
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to get pateint_name from this with patientid using LINQ in c#

I have tried like

```
var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(ResponseContent);
jsonLinq["appointments"].AsEnumerable().Select(p => p["patient_name"]).Where(s => Convert.ToString(s["patient_id"]).Equals(2)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonLinq["appointments"].AsEnumerable().Where(s => Convert.ToString(s["patient_id"]).Equals(2)).Select(p => p["patient_name"]).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Got the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Start with `Where` and then `Select`

```
var results =  jsonLinq["appointments"]
                .Where(s => s["patient_id"].ToString() == "1")
                .Select(p => p["patient_name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var name = jsonLinq.SelectToken($"$.appointments[?(@.patient_id == '{idToSearch}')].patient_name")
                   .Value<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of `Select` and `Where` is important here. You need to filter the full "patient" entries with `Where` first, before you extract the "patient_name" property with `Select`. As soon as you run the `Select` mapping function, your `IEnumerable` will only contain what you selected, not the element that you selected it from.

`Select` before `Where` (doesn't work):

```cs
var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(ResponseContent);
// whole JObject
jsonLinq["appointments"]
// "appointments" object
  .AsEnumerable()
  // "appointments" as list of KeyValuePair<string, JToken>
  .Select(p => p["patient_name"])
  // list of all "patient_name" JTokens
  .Where(s => Convert.ToString(s["patient_id"]).Equals(2))
  // Error: JTokens "Jairaj Test" and "Test Physician" don't have any "patient_id" property
```

`Where` before `Select` (works):

```cs
var jsonLinq = JObject.Parse(ResponseContent);
// whole JObject
jsonLinq["appointments"]
// "appointments" object
  .AsEnumerable()
  // "appointments" as list of KeyValuePair<string, JToken>
  .Where(s => Convert.ToString(s["patient_id"]).Equals(2))
  // filtered list of all patient objects where "patient_id" is "2"
  .Select(p => p["patient_name"])
  // list of all "patient_names" from the previously filtered list
```

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON is non dynamic, you could also create some model classes that represent your JSON data:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [JsonProperty("patient_id")]
    public string PatientId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("patient_name")]
    public string PatientName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("physician_name")]
    public string PhysicianName { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }]
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("appointments")]
    public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize and fetch the patient names with `Where()` and `Select()`:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

var patient = jsonObject
    .Appointments
    .Where(a => a.PatientId.Equals("2"))
    .Select(a => a.PatientName);
```

Or you can simply just retrieve the first one found with`FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var patient = jsonObject
   .Appointments
   .FirstOrDefault(a => a.PatientId.Equals("2"))
   .PatientName;
```